# Как сделать чтобы бот отвечал на сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Как сделать так чтобы бот при определенном сообщении отвечал на него?

Пример нужного результата:

[image: пример нужного результата]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный кусок кода дает именно тот результат, который у вас на скриншоте

```
@dp.message_handler(text='бот')
async def mess(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer('Я тут')
```